# Matching case-insensitive in BSD awk for loop with gsub

Tags: awk

I am attempting to redact names from emails.
I can not get the the loop to match case-insensitive.
I have tried various methods with IGNORECASE=1, and tolower(), but The best I get is exact matches, and all lower case matches.

Here is the loop code

```
for file in $(ls $emailDir/*.txt)
do
    awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]="■■REDACTED■■";next} {for ( i in a) gsub(i,"■■REDACTED■■")}1' $namelList $file > temp.txt
    mv temp.txt $file
done
```

Comment: is your awk `GNU awk`?

Comment: Note `for file in $(...)` can be written as just `for file in $emailDir/*.txt`

Answer (score 1):

- If your awk is gnu awk, you can use `IGNORECASE` built-in variable:

  ```
  kent$  echo "aBcDe"|awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '1+gsub(/bcd/,"foo")'  
  afooe
  ```
- What you can also think about is, when you store the data of first file into array, you make the index lowercase: `a[tolower($0)]="■■REDACTED■■"`. And in the 2nd part, do a `$0=tolower($0)` before calling `gsub()`. **This will make your output all in lower case**.

Comment: Unfortunately it BSD awk running on OS X. I did attempt to use "awk -v IGNORECASE=1"  but it had no effect.

Comment: No joy with `awk 'NR==FNR {a[tolower($0)]="■■REDACTED■■";next} {for ( i in a)  $0=tolower($0); gsub(i,"■■REDACTED■■")}1'`